# PHP - error logging through htaccess - Error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to log all PHP errors by activating the logging in htaccess but for some reason, I always end up with a http 500 error.

I have stored the .htaccess in a separate directory to avoid messing up with the rest of my site.

The content of the .htaccess file is the following:

```
php_flag display_errors off 
php_flag log_errors On 
php_value error_log /home/xxxxx/www/cache/php_logs/errors.log
```

The path exists and permissions are set to 777

In my PHP file I have only:

```
<?PHP
  echo "hello world";
?>
```

If I remove the content of the .htaccess file, I can see "hello world" but as soon as I activate logging, it ends up with an internal server error (error 500).

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to enable display_errors to see what's causing the 500 error?

Comment: yes, I also get an error 500. It's like the php_flag instruction is not accepted at all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this method is no longer supported (using htaccess for logging). I have found an alternative that does the same:

- create a .user.ini file in my root directory
- add logging in the .user.ini file:

> ```
> log_errors = On
> error_log = /home/xxxx/www/cache/php_logs/errors.log
> ```

By doing this, it will log all errors in the specified directory and it works with shared hosting solutions. (at least with mine).